# How is "const [a] = someArray" assignment called?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am seeing an assignment like this:

```
const [a] = someArray
```

Which seems to assign first item from `someArray` to `a` constant. If so, it is the same as `const a = someArray[0]` but in a new way.

Is it true? How is this assignment called so that I could find more information about it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: destructuring assignment

Comment: const [a] = [1, 2, 3] // a = 1 so essentially the Array destructuring-assignment is a way to access indexed parts of an Array. const [a, ...rest] = [1, 2, 3] // a = 1, rest = [2, 3] const [first, second, third] = [1, 2, 3] // first = 1, second = 2, third = 3